# Сравнение содержимого строк в table (без jQuery)

Tags: javascript

Добрый вечер. Нужна функция, которая сравнивала бы все ячейки `td` на предмет содержимого.

Например есть 5 ячеек. Надо чтоб логический оператор `if` сравнил с примером и выдал мне ответ (true/false)

Наверняка понятно, что ниже написанная функция работает не так, как мне надо. Я  понимаю принцип работы этой функции, но самому написать ту, которая мне нужна, уже который день не получается

```
function proverka() {
  var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
  for (var i = 0, row; row = myTable.rows[i]; i++) {
    for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
      if (myTable.rows[0].cells[i].innerText == myTable.rows[0].cells[i].innerText && myTable.rows[0].cells[i].innerText == "X") {
        cnsole.log("verj")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: В чём смысл сравнения `myTable.rows[0].cells[i].innerText` с самим собой? И переменная `j` нигде не используется!

Comment: @sercxjo ни в чём , это функция здесь что было легко на нём показать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Должно работать как то так:

```js
var table = document.getElementById( "myTable" );

for ( var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++ ) {
 if (table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML === table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML)
   alert(true);
  else
   alert(false);
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>bbb</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Дальше сами.

-------------------- ДОБАВЛЕНО ----------------------

```js
var table = document.getElementById( "myTable" );

for ( var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++ ) {
 for ( var j = 0; j < table.rows[0].cells.length; j++ ) {
   alert("indexes x:" + i + " y:" + j + " = " + table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML);
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>o</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

----------ДОБАВЛЕНО---------

```js
var table = document.getElementById( "myTable" );

for ( var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++ ) {
 for ( var j = 0; j < table.rows[0].cells.length; j++ ) {
   //alert("indexes x:" + i + " y:" + j + " = " + table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML);
    if (table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML === table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML)
     alert(true);
    else
     alert(false);
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>o</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

--------- ДОБАВЛЕНО ----------

```js
var table = document.getElementById( "myTable" );

var flag; // флаг проверки на победу

for ( var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++ ) {
 for ( var j = 0; j < table.rows[0].cells.length; j++ ) {
   //alert("indexes x:" + i + " y:" + j + " = " + table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML);
    if (table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML === table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML)
     flag = true; // все хорошо
    else {
     flag = false; // ложь
      continue; // найдена ложь оборвать цикл и продолжить
    }
  }
  
  if (flag === true)
   alert("победа " + table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML + " в строке " + i);
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>o</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>o</td>
        <td>o</td>
        <td>o</td>
        <td>o</td>
        <td>o</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @perect я так писал  , здесь обязательно надо подчеркнуть что кроме того что их innerHTML равны друг друга ,  ещё и должно быть X или Օ а то при пустых  ячейках тоже будет true давать , во вторых, такой способ  если у тебя есть больше 2-ух td в table-е он работать не будет , так как ну например у меня есть table с шестью td он найдя две совпадения при каждом ходе будет возвращать мне значение true , и дело в том что значение  myTable.rows.length произвольное , нельзя написать для трех , четырёх или пяти , функция везде должна работать

Comment: @Тигран, сформулируйте правильно правила сравнение полей (недостаточно данных для алгоритма), во вторых я вам принцип обработки таблицы только показал, ну а в третьих смотрите полный цикл обработки всей таблицы (добавил мой в ответ).

Comment: весь вопрос ведь в этом , я могу написать для трёх , четырёх и сколько угодно раз , но это только для конкретного случая , а вот как написать что это повторилось n-но раз , ума не приложу

Comment: `table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML === table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML` 
вместо этого я бы хотел написать чтоб cells[0] сравнил с следующим и так столько раз пока вся строка не проверится

Comment: просто нужно правильно составить задачу перед алгоритмом а то есть то что хочешь получить. что вам хочется увидеть в итоге?

например разберем одну строку таблицы, если все элементы в строке одинаковы то любой элемент строки можно сравнивать с первым элементом.

Если не поняли задавайте вопрос

Comment: добавил пример в мой ответ, смотрите

Comment: напишу чуть попозже

Comment: я два дня назад писал что-то наподобие этого и вот какой вопрос  стал передо мной  ,,,чтоб этот способ сработал  я должен ещё одно сравнение написать , на примере этого , когда у меня будет 5  true  alert("выиграли такие то") ,но я так не смог , или может быть я по другой дороге иду ?

Comment: 5 true - это равносильно не одному false в строке, смотрите добавление в моем ответе

Comment: немного модифицировал последний код, проверьте

Comment: там где вы поставили флаг ,мне кажется  то что надо , я именно это   не мог решить ( да и не знал если честно) , щяс протестирую

Comment: под моим кодом есть кнопочка **выполнить**

Comment: Понял что за флаг

Comment: да ,  знаю но  лучше сразу в код поставить и проверит ,, так вот что получается ,,,, что то не так ,  хотя принцип правилен ,разберусь уже ,  благодарю , очень помогли

Comment: у меня к Вам один вопрос , смотрите 
Вы иф поставили в цикле 
`if (flag === true)`
да,  есть такая запись `alert("победа " + table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML + " в строке " + i);`
но вот в чём вопрос выводя иф из цикла (у меня вместо алерта теперь стоит такая запись ` if (flag === true){console.log("победа " )` ) вся функция сравнивания начинает по другому считывать, и я не пойму как, и да я хорошенько изменил код , если интересно могу скинуть

Comment: Да , ещё может возникнуть вопрос а зачем выводить если без этого работает нормально , дело в том что и без этого,  во время сравнивания возникаюткое какие то ошибки (хотя если вывести их из цикла , то ошибок становится больше), ну кроме этого хочу понять что к чему

Comment: для уведомления .

Comment: @Тигран, старайтесь правильней формулировать вопрос, `вся функция сравнивания начинает по другому считывать` - для меня функция это область кода помеченная словом **function**, видимо вы имели участок кода. По моим предположениям при изменении на  ` if (flag === true){console.log("победа " )` у вас в лог должно попасть два одинаковых сообщения, если прогнать его по моей таблице.

тигран, если у вас появились какие то дополнительные вопросы не стесняйтесь задавать их в новом вопросе, если он не дублирует текущий вопрос.

Comment: ,постараюсь,, спасибо